# Android - Is it possible to get two different apk just by cleaning the project?

Tags: android

I use the same source to make apk files.
But I found that I get the different apk files just because of cleaning the project.
Why I think I got two different apk files, I try to change locale, one apk got the language changed, and one is not.

I think there might be something wrong in my "`AndroidManifest.xml`" file.
Could this kind of thing  happen?

Comment: Where did you get these apk's? on an emulator or a real device? on multiple emulators or the same one?

Comment: I test my apk files using same phone. And I'am sorry, I cannot put the manifest here. And sometimes, I got warning when I modified the manifest file, but just clean the project, there is just no the warning.

Comment: which warning did you get when you modified manifest file ?

Comment: this is my warning:Exported activity does not require permission and I use "android:launchMode="singleTask" and "<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />" to that activity.

Answer (score 0):

i think you got two app launcher ... pls check your manifest file for this..

```
 <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

And this should be declared only once in manifest.. check any duplicate is there?